# Dropdown box that when a key is pressed, jumps to selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Combo box that defines the contents of other boxes on the screen.

So if I was to, for example, type "Apple" in my Combo box for employee names, it will cause an error because there are no "Apple" employees in my database, meaning nothing will be retrieved to populate the rest of the form.

Is there a property I can set or code snippet I can write to make sure anything the user types in the combo box will instead highlight a selection from the draw?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` (instead of `DropDown`). Then the user can stil type, but the `Combobox` only switches the selection if such an Element exists.

(However this does change the ComboBox-Appearence, so it no longer looks like "Freetext" available)

Set `AutoCompleteMode` to `Suggest` and `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems` in order to allow typing of more than just the first letter. (The Combobox will expand and switch the element as the user types in more letters.)

Answer (score 0):

check the datasource(datatable,dataset etc etc) count  that you are binding into the ComboBox

```
if(DataSource!=null && DataSource.rows.count>0)
{
   combobox.datasource=DataSource;
   combobox.refresh();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do the following things:

1.Take a TextBox and set the properties of the TextBox as 
`AutoCompleteMode=SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource = CustomSource`.

2.Load a values you want, in the datatable (probably Employees name or any other column you want).

3.Call the below method in you page load or any event you want.

```
public bool AutoComplete()
{
    try
    { 
        DataTable dtEmpName=/////// store the employees name in this DataTable.
        var empNames = dtEmpName.Select(s => s.EmpName('the column you want').Distinct().ToArray();
        /////// Auto complete Name from Surname
        AutoCompleteStringCollection instcol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        instcol.AddRange(empNames);
        txtEmpNames.AutoCompleteCustomSource = instcol;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```